# how to select row using laravel Raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to select all rows of given date from my Activity Table. And for that I used the `whereRaw()` Clause. Here is my code for doing that:

```
$activities = Activity::whereRaw('Date(created_at) as date',$date)->get();
dd($activities);
```

But I got an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as date' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `activities` where Date(created_at) as date)

Please help me to solve this problem. Here is a `dd()` of `$date`:

```
"2019-12-12"
```

Comment: You can't use column aliases in a where query, and you're not attempting to bind anything. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods for how to use the raw methods.

Comment: select rows of given date sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: i update my post please see this

Comment: That makes a bit more sense. Anyway, why `whereRaw()`? Laravel has a `whereDate()` method that should work for this.

Comment: and @aynber i read th docs and then try get the result but no luck

Comment: yes @TimLewis i used to think in a complex way thats why the prbolem occurs btw thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Generally, try to use Laravel methods for database, unless you specifically need a raw query. Just be aware that if you changed DB type (from MySQL to something else), your `whereRaws`, etc. might need to be changed to work with this new database. Laravel's methods work will all (or most) databases without modification, so best to use those first.

Comment: thanks for also share your valuable opinion

Answer (score 2):

Then go for:

```
$activities = Activity::whereDate('created_at', $date)
            ->get();
```

Remeber that **$date** must be in date format.
Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses for reference.